# Ubuntu phone replacing Android 2.2.2

Tags: phone

Is it possible to change my android phone running 2.2.2 to Ubuntu? If not, how can I get Ubuntu for android? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but as of the moment Ubuntu touch only works on the nexus devices, more specifically:

- Nexus 7 (2013 only)
- Nexus 4

You can port Ubuntu Touch on your phone if you can invest the amount of time and effort it will require. Check out the [official porting guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Porting) for more info.